# How to split a mark-down Japanese string into atomic parts?

Tags: c#, regex

Consider I have a string as follows.

```
string input = "合{あい}気{き}道{どう}生{う}まれる昨日{きのう}から揚{あ}げそば";
```

What I want to get is an array as follows.

```
string[] output = {"合{あい}", "気{き}", "道{どう}", 
                   "生{う}", "まれる", "昨日{きのう}", 
                   "から", "揚{あ}", "げそば"};
```

The pseudo rules to find the atomic parts:

- one or more kanji charactes followed by `{` followed by one or more hiragana characters followed by `}`
- one or more hiragana characters that are not enclosed between `{` and `}`.

I am not familiar with regex. I also have no idea how to distinguish kanji from hiragana. Could you help me to solve it in C#?

Comment: Does this one work for you: [`[一-龯]+{\p{IsHiragana}+}|\p{IsHiragana}+(?![^{}]*})`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%e4%b8%80-%e9%be%af%5d%2b%7b%5cp%7bIsHiragana%7d%2b%7d%7c%5cp%7bIsHiragana%7d%2b(%3f!%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d)&i=%e5%90%88%7b%e3%81%82%e3%81%84%7d%e6%b0%97%7b%e3%81%8d%7d%e9%81%93%7b%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%7d%e7%94%9f%7b%e3%81%86%7d%e3%81%be%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e6%98%a8%e6%97%a5%7b%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ae%e3%81%86%7d%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e6%8f%9a%7b%e3%81%82%7d%e3%81%92%e3%81%9d%e3%81%b0)?

Comment: @stribizhev: Yes. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
[一-龯]+{\p{IsHiragana}+}|\p{IsHiragana}+(?![^{}]*})
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%E4%B8%80-%E9%BE%AF%5D%2B%7B%5Cp%7BIsHiragana%7D%2B%7D%7C%5Cp%7BIsHiragana%7D%2B(%3F!%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2A%7D)&i=%E5%90%88%7B%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%7D%E6%B0%97%7B%E3%81%8D%7D%E9%81%93%7B%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%7D%E7%94%9F%7B%E3%81%86%7D%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E6%98%A8%E6%97%A5%7B%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%86%7D%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E6%8F%9A%7B%E3%81%82%7D%E3%81%92%E3%81%9D%E3%81%B0)

It contains two alternatives:

- `[一-龯]+{\p{IsHiragana}+}` - matches 1 or more Kanji (`[一-龯]+`, borrowed from [*terrancesnyder*](https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094)) followed by 1 or more Hiragana symbols inside `{...}` or...
- `\p{IsHiragana}+(?![^{}]*})` - 1 or more Hiragana that is not followed by characters other than `{` or `}` and then a `}`.

Comment: I don't understand your last rule "1 or more Hiragana that is not followed by characters other than `{` or `}` and then a `}`."

Comment: You have defined a rule: *one or more hiragana characters that are not enclosed between `{` and `}`.* If the `{` and `}` are paired, we can simply check if there is no `}` somewhere after the hiragana characters. If there can be unpaired, you need to use `[一-龯]+{\p{IsHiragana}+}|(?<!{[^{}]*)\p{IsHiragana}+(?![^{}]*})`, which is less efficient since it has a variable-width lookbehind. If it does not work, please let me know.

Comment: I noticed the  [modified version](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bIsHiragana%7d%2b%7c%5b%e4%b8%80-%e9%be%af%5d%2b%7b%5cp%7bIsHiragana%7d%2b%7d&i=%e5%90%88%7b%e3%81%82%e3%81%84%7d%e6%b0%97%7b%e3%81%8d%7d%e9%81%93%7b%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%7d%e7%94%9f%7b%e3%81%86%7d%e3%81%be%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e6%98%a8%e6%97%a5%7b%e3%81%8d%e3%81%ae%e3%81%86%7d%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e6%8f%9a%7b%e3%81%82%7d%e3%81%92%e3%81%9d%e3%81%b0%e6%bc%a2%e5%ad%97%7b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%93%e3%81%98%7d) does also work.